# Why is Action Listener malfunctioning?

Tags: java, swing, actionevent

I am developing a basic Tic Tac Toe game using Java. It is supposed to have 9 buttons in a grid, and when you click one, X appears. Once you've clicked on a button, a kind of switch variable `i` should change value, so the next time you click O appears. There are no syntax errors, however there is a problem. When I click on a button, X does appear, but then when I click on another button, instead of O appearing, X appears again.
This is my logical code.

```
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) {
            int i = 1;
            boolean b1xon=false;
            boolean b2xon=false;
            boolean b3xon=false;
            boolean b4xon=false;
            boolean b5xon=false;
            boolean b6xon=false;
            boolean b7xon=false;
            boolean b8xon=false;
            boolean b9xon=false;
            boolean b1oon=false;
            boolean b2oon=false;
            boolean b3oon=false;
            boolean b4oon=false;
            boolean b5oon=false;
            boolean b6oon=false;
            boolean b7oon=false;
            boolean b8oon=false;
            boolean b9oon=false;
            boolean win=false;

                if ((evt.getSource() == b1) && (i == 1)) {
                    b1.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b1 && i == 2) {
                    b1.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b2 && i == 1) {
                    b2.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b2xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b2 && i == 2) {
                    b2.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b2oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b3 && i == 1) {
                    b3.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b3xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b3 && i == 2) {
                    b3.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b3oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b4 && i == 1) {
                    b4.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b4xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b4 && i == 2) {
                    b4.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b4oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b5 && i == 1) {
                    b5.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b5xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b5 && i == 2) {
                    b5.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b5oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b6 && i == 1) {
                    b6.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b6xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b6 && i == 2) {
                    b6.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b6oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b7 && i == 1) {
                    b7.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b7xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b7 && i == 2) {
                    b7.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b7oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b8 && i == 1) {
                    b8.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b8xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b8 && i == 2) {
                    b8.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b8oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b9 && i == 1) {
                    b9.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b9xon=true;
                }
                else if(evt.getSource() == b9 && i==1){
                    b9.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b9oon=true;
                }
                if((b1xon&&b2xon&&b3xon)||(b4xon&&b5xon&&b6xon)||(b7xon&&b8xon&&b9xon)||(b1xon&&b4xon&&b7xon)||(b2xon&&b5xon&&b8xon)||(b3xon&&b6xon&&b9xon)||(b1xon&&b5xon&&b9xon)||(b3xon&&b5xon&&b7xon)){
                 win=true;
                }
                else if((b1oon&&b2oon&&b3oon)||(b4oon&&b5oon&&b6oon)||(b7oon&&b8oon&&b9oon)||(b1oon&&b4oon&&b7oon)||(b2oon&&b5oon&&b8oon)||(b3oon&&b6oon&&b9oon)||(b1oon&&b5oon&&b9oon)||(b3oon&&b5oon&&b7oon)){
                 win=true;
                }
```

Comment: Every time `actionPerformed` is called, all of the variables inside of it are reset (re-instantiated). You should use class variables.

Comment: `i` needs to be declared in a scope "above" the listener.

Comment: @StevenHansen so should all of the other variables.

Comment: Side comment: Is there a reason you're not using arrays?  Any time you copy-and-paste code 18 times you should be thinking that there must be a simpler way to accomplish it.